# Convert AVI file to WMV in C++ DirectShow; GraphEdit and source code

Tags: c++, video, com, directshow

I would like to make a tool to get an AVI file as input and convert it to WMV file and save it on my hard disc.
In GraphEdit I was successful to do it as you can see in

[image]

I started to make the COM C++ code for the same task to have the same effect but I don't get where the issue might be that prevent me to have the final converted file.
This is the code I have written (there's a lot of memory leak). 
I checked all returned values and all are OKAY, so there is no error in calls.

```
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Strmiids.lib") 
#define AVI_FILE_PATH L"C:\\...\\Desktop\\oo.avi"
#define WMV_FILE_PATH L"C:\\...\\Desktop\\BRGMovie.wmv"

int main() {
    IGraphBuilder* pGraph             = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pSource            = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pAviSplitter       = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pMjpegDecompressor = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pSmartTee          = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pAviMux            = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pFileWriter        = NULL;
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2* pBuild     = NULL;
    IFileSourceFilter*  FileSource    = NULL;

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&pGraph            );
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AsyncReader, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pSource           );
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AviSplitter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pAviSplitter      );
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MjpegDec,    NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pMjpegDecompressor);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SmartTee,    NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pSmartTee         );
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AviDest,     NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pAviMux           );
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileWriter,  NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pFileWriter       );
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileSource,  NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFileSourceFilter, (void**)&FileSource);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**)&pBuild);

    pGraph->AddFilter(pSource,            NULL);
    pGraph->AddFilter(pAviSplitter,       NULL);
    pGraph->AddFilter(pMjpegDecompressor, NULL);
    pGraph->AddFilter(pSmartTee,          NULL);
    pGraph->AddFilter(pAviMux,            NULL);
    pGraph->AddFilter(pFileWriter,        NULL);

    pSource->QueryInterface(IID_IFileSourceFilter, (void**)&FileSource);
    FileSource->Load(AVI_FILE_PATH, NULL);

    pBuild->SetOutputFileName(&MEDIASUBTYPE_Asf, WMV_FILE_PATH, &pAviMux, NULL);
    pBuild->RenderStream(NULL, &MEDIATYPE_Video, pSource, 0, pAviMux);

    IEnumPins*  EnumPins = NULL;
    IPin*       OutPin   = NULL;
    IPin*       InPin    = NULL;
    ULONG       fetched  = NULL;
    PIN_INFO    pinfo;

    // find source output
    pSource->EnumPins(&EnumPins);
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &OutPin, &fetched);
    EnumPins->Release();

    // find AviSplitter input
    pAviSplitter->EnumPins(&EnumPins);
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &InPin, &fetched);
    InPin->QueryPinInfo(&pinfo);
    pinfo.pFilter->Release();       
    pGraph->Connect(OutPin, InPin);
    InPin->Release();
    OutPin->Release();

    // find AviSplitter upper output
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &OutPin, &fetched);
    OutPin->QueryPinInfo(&pinfo);
    pinfo.pFilter->Release();

    EnumPins->Skip(1);
    EnumPins->Release();

    // find MjpegDecompressor input
    pMjpegDecompressor->EnumPins(&EnumPins);
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &InPin, &fetched);    

    pGraph->Connect(OutPin, InPin);
    InPin->Release();
    OutPin->Release();

    // find MjpegDecompressor output
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &OutPin, &fetched);
    OutPin->QueryPinInfo(&pinfo);
    pinfo.pFilter->Release();
    EnumPins->Release();

    // find SmartTee input
    pSmartTee->EnumPins(&EnumPins);
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &InPin, &fetched);

    pGraph->Connect(OutPin, InPin);
    InPin->Release();
    OutPin->Release();

    // find SmartTee output
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &OutPin, &fetched);
    OutPin->QueryPinInfo(&pinfo);
    pinfo.pFilter->Release();

    EnumPins->Skip(1);

    // find AVIMux input
    pAviMux->EnumPins(&EnumPins);
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &InPin, &fetched);

    pGraph->Connect(OutPin, InPin);
    InPin->Release();
    OutPin->Release();

    EnumPins->Skip(1);

    // find AVIMux output
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &OutPin, &fetched);
    OutPin->QueryPinInfo(&pinfo);
    pinfo.pFilter->Release();   

    // find FileWriter input
    pFileWriter->EnumPins(&EnumPins);
    EnumPins->Reset();
    EnumPins->Next(1, &InPin, &fetched);
    EnumPins->Release();
    pGraph->Connect(OutPin, InPin);
    InPin->Release();
    OutPin->Release();
    FileSource->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Edited:

```
int main() {
    IGraphBuilder* pGraph = NULL;
    IBaseFilter*   pASFWriter = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2* pBuild = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WMAsfWriter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pASFWriter);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**)&pBuild);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);
    hr = pBuild->SetOutputFileName(&MEDIASUBTYPE_Asf, WMV_FILE_PATH, &pASFWriter, NULL);
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(AVI_FILE_PATH, NULL);
    hr = pControl->Run();
    long evCode;
    pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided filter graph does not produce a WMV (also known as ASF) file. Instead, you are trying to create an AVI file with .WMV extension (you are using AVI Mux!).

Second issue is use of Smart Tee filter, it should not be used in such transcoding graph. Smart Tee has its own (and documented) designation.

To produce a WMV file, you need to connect MJPEG decoder output to input of an instance of [WM ASF Writer Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/wm-asf-writer-filter). The filter needs to be configured and have a profile attached.

For more information, see [Creating ASF Files in DirectShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/creating-asf-files-in-directshow).

Also [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/building-filter-graphs-to-write-asf-files) right on your question:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment. I tried to use the graph from the MSDN website. There is this approach in [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318239(v=vs.85).aspx) and they say _The easiest way is to add the WM ASF Writer to the filter graph and then use the IGraphBuilder::RenderFile method to build the graph automatically_. Following that I tried to write this code, but still does not work.

Comment: the new code is in Edited section above. There is also the manual approach in the same MSDN link, but to start, I would like to follow the automatic way of converting AVI to WMV. If I need to manually configure the ASF Writer, which did not hinted for the automatic approach, could you please give me some small coding hints how to do it?

Comment: Instead of `SetOutputFileName` and `RenderFile` I would recommend doing `CoCreateInstance` + `AddFilter` + `IPin.Connect` calls to build the graph accurately and with fine control. Also, you need to set up WM ASF Writer profile before connecting the filter pins.